# Word 2007-How to remove all bullets but keep numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets

When I copy a web page into word, often word adds bullet points where there were none in the original web page, which need to be removed.

Sometimes there ARE numbered parts in the web page which need to be kept.

Clicking Home Tab, bullets icon (twice) removes both the numbers AND bullets.  I've tried to construct a macro and see clicking the bullet icon results in the command `Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph`

Can anyone help with a way to KEEP the numbers and remove only the unwanted bullets?

OR, a way to stop them appearing in the first place?  (Would be even better!)

PS: I copy the selected area from the web page Ctrl_C and paste it into Word (as advised in [How to Copy a Web Page to Word   Chron.com](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-word-42912.html), please dont suggest saving html and opening in word- try with this page and I get this:

[image: This web page saved as html and opened in word]